# Python parsing css files and generating a base64 url for all images and types

Tags: python, css, parsing

I am trying to write a python parser to generate a base64 url for all images and font files (*.ttf) (it'd be good if I can extend it to all external dependencies, but this works for now):

I know how to generate the base64 of an image etc. How do I go about parsing the css stylesheet to find all images and ttf files included in the css.

```
from cssutils import CSSParser


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = CSSParser()
    sheet = parser.parseFile('pressbooks-custom-css.css')
    for rule in sheet.cssRules:
        print(rule)
        print(rule.cssText)
```

Here is a sample css file, however I'd like to make a generic parser to do this task:

https://gist.github.com/nipunarora/9da79552efefea09ab9e3bc0f1a70ecd

Comment: Do you have a sample css file that you want to process?

Comment: Its supposed to be generic, but I will add an example as well

Comment: @BillBell - I've updated with a sample as you can see   src: url(assets/WWDesigns.ttf) format("truetype");
is a ttf that i'd like to data urlify